# setFullScreen in a webview

Tags: android, webview

Good evening,

I have developed in Android studio an app which opens an internet page. I wanted to have it full screen (i.e. no notification bar at the top of the screen). Looking at the forums, I added this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

//... some additional code here ...

    View decorView = setFullscreen();
    decorView
            .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                    setFullscreen();
                }
            });

    webView.loadUrl(myUrl);

}

private View setFullscreen() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    return decorView;
}

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        setFullscreen();
    }
}
```

Everything works almost perfectly, except when I click on one of the link of my loaded page : the top notification bar is again displayed when another page is loaded.

Anyone has an idea about what I missed?

Thanks for your kind help and best wishes,
Laurent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can use this code in your activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

}

it will make your activity fullscreen no status bar.

Comment: That's great it rocks, thanks a lot and have a great weekend :)